# Can we compare the skill or intelligence necessary to do an intrinsic good vs evil?

Tags: good-and-evil, intelligence

Can we compare the skill or intelligence necessary to do an intrinsic good vs evil? I was just thinking whether e.g. a skilled murderer can be compared with the skill of being a good mother. There seems to be a mental block there, when I try to compare Jack the Ripper with The Virgin Mary, and I just wondered whether it is meaningful.

I suppose virtue ethics would be the easiest way to answer, but I'm especially interested in absolutist duties and not really at all utilitarianism. I welcome an answer from any cogent moral perspective.

Comment: Unless you are more specific about what definition of good and evil you are going with it's difficult to answer your question.

Comment: an example isn't enough @armand do you mean a meta-ethics, like "non-cognitivism" or similar? as i've said before, idt that's how discussing ethics always works

Comment: Your question is not about ethics, it is not a "what do good or bad mean?" question. Instead, it seems to have an assumption about what good and evil are and then ask about the respective level of skill necessary to perform each. But actually many conceptions of "good" and "evil" have been proposed by philosophers (some even arguing those are meaningless). You give the exemple of a skilled murderer as an evil person, but some argue there can be good murders (killing Hitler, etc...). If people who answer don't share your assumptions you will never get a quality answer, it's in your interest.

Comment: what do you need to know to generate opinions on this question @armand that's what i'm thinking

Comment: Skills and intelligence necessary vary widely already within "good" and "evil", by whatever definition of them, depending on specific type of "good" or "evil" performed. Would it be any easier comparing skills of virgin Mary to those of Edison (assuming his inventions were "good")? It seems to me that the necessary skills depend on morality-neutral characteristics of activities involved rather than on polarity attached to them (which is easily switched by a broader context). Perhaps, there are some "good"/"evil"-specific skills but then you do need to spell out what your "good" and "evil" are.

Answer (score -1):

There are different types of intelligence. You can not compare between the intelligence of God and intelligence of Devil.However at least they are both skilled in employing a method. In this sense they can be compared. (In fact there is a method to madness. )

There is no point in comparing a murderer and a mother. But if you still want to compare then I can definitely tell you that both are intelligent enough to employ a method.

Comment: ai had a method, but is it truly intelligent?

Comment: AI gives answers based on data it has. It is an intelligent design and it shows the intelligence of its creator. But AI itself is not intelligent. AI is like a mirror of its intelligent creator.

Answer (score -1):

Not really. Morality, even in deontological systems with intrinsic good and evil, has to do with circumstances of permissibility or obligation. Skill has to do with actions and practical constraints. Your examples of "murderer" and "good mother" are importing the circumstances of permissibility and obligation into the actions themselves, which is resulting in confusion.

To be a murderer means in part that the person against whom you are using lethal force is a person against whom it is morally impermissible to use lethal force. Fighting off genocidal invaders requires more or less the same skills as murder. Most deontological ethical systems would permit or oblige one to resist genocidal invaders with lethal force.

To be a good mother means in part that the child you're raising is a person that you are morally permitted or obligated to raise. Raising kidnapped children requires more or less the same skills as being a good mother. Most deontological ethical systems would oblige you to surrender kidnapped children to their real parents and cease attempting to raise them.

Comment: i think you are right i've confused you anyway. you don't seem to answer the question i wanted to ask, at all

Comment: intelligfence has nothing to do with morality then?